# Drupal Solr: Search by user email

Tags: 7, search

I have Profile2 module installed and Solr search module.
Is there a way to search for users by e-mail with Drupal Solr ?

Comment: Which module you use? apachesolr or search_api_solr?

Comment: I am using apachesolr module.

Comment: but I am ok to switch to another one if this will help me.